# PDO Mysql WHERE LIKE query implementation

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this simple function in a class:

```
public function getSearchResults($selectedMethod, $query)
{

        $this->_query = '%'.$query.'%';
        $this->_selectedMethod = $selectedMethod;

        $db = mysql_init();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM plantsRecords WHERE ? LIKE ?";
        $prq = $db->prepare($sql);

        $prq->bindValue(1,$this->_selectedMethod,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $prq->bindValue(2,$this->_query,PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $prq->execute();
}
```

The problem is that something is happening with WHERE and LIKE. If i put a standard column_name the query works, but if i assign it with a `?` it doesn't. I read all similar questions in this site but everyone has the parameter of WHERE statement standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind the column name as a parameter. You'll need to do something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM plantsRecords WHERE " . $this->_selectedMethod . " LIKE ?";
$prq = $db->prepare($sql);
$prq->bindValue(1, $this->_query,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prq->execute();
```

You'll need to make sure that `$this->_selectedMethod` is not chosen by the user. If it is chosen by the user, then you will need to whitelist the allowed column names.